# Set MSBuild Web Publish Property "ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol" from Command Line

Tags: .net-4.0, build, msbuild, nant

I'm using NAnt to build my project and publish web site project(s). I'd like to include the PDBs in the resulting package. How can I set the `ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol` property from the command line when I execute `msbuild`?

I tried adding it to the list of parameters but I'm not seeing the PDBs still. My `exec` task looks like this:

```
<exec program="${MSBuildPath}" workingdir="${path::get-full-path(PublishWebProject.SourcePath)}\">
  <!-- Don't show the logo. -->
  <arg value="/nologo"/>
  <!-- Build w/o Clean -->
  <arg value="/t:Build"/>
  <!-- Configuration, Output, Options, No Warnings -->
  <arg value="/p:OutputPath=bin\;OutDir=${path::get-full-path(PublishWebProject.OutputPath)};Configuration=${Configuration};Platform=Any CPU;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False;WarningLevel=0;RunCodeAnalysis=false;ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false"/>
  <!-- Quiet -->
  <arg value="/v:q"/>
  <!-- Project Path -->
  <arg value="${PublishWebProject.ProjectFileName}"/>
</exec>
```

And here is the actual call to MSBuild:

```
 [exec] Starting 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe (/nologo /t:Build "/p:OutputPath=bin\;OutDir=D:\Projects\XYZ\Publish\Release-Production\CommonWeb\;Configuration=Release-Production;Platform=Any CPU;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False;WarningLevel=0;RunCodeAnalysis=false;ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false" /v:q CommonWeb.csproj)' in 'D:\Projects\XYZ\Source\CommonWeb\'
```

Which would equate to:

```
D:\Projects\XYZ\Source\CommonWeb> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /nologo /t:Build "/p:OutputPath=bin\;OutDir=D:\Projects\XYZ\Publish\Release-Production\CommonWeb\;Configuration=Release-Production;Platform=Any CPU;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False;WarningLevel=0;RunCodeAnalysis=false;ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false" /v:q CommonWeb.csproj
```

I've also tried setting the `UseWPP_CopyWebApplication` to false but this didn't help either.

Comment: could you post the NAnt output. I suspect unquoted property args might be an issue

Comment: NAnt automatically quotes the arguments if needed. For instance, my long argument which starts with `/p:OutputPath...` end up as `"/p:OutputPath..."` since it has spaces in the value of the `OutDir` parameter. And the build works fine as-is, I'm just not getting the PDBs. I'm not even convinced that the `ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol` property is a valid one to send through. I'll post the complete command line in a few minutes...

Comment: My next guess would be setting debug info. Find my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your project file contains information on output debug info. Try setting debug info to `pdb-only`:

```
<arg value="/debug:pdbonly" />
```

Comment: That gives me: `MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: /debug:pdbonly` which I kind of expected since it's not listed as a switch here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311(v=vs.100).aspx

I do have the 'Properties > Build > Output > Advanced > Output > Debug Info' setting set to "pdb-only" in the project file. I also unchecked the `Properties > Package/Publish Web > Items to deploy > Exclude generated debug symbols`. To no avail.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that setting output debug info is build-configuration-sensitive? Set `Properties > Build > Configuration` to `All Configurations` prior to setting `Debug Info` to `pdb-only`.

Comment: Yes, `pdb-only` is selected for all of my build configurations (and the aforementioned checkbox is un-checked).